# Find $a_{ij}$ in $v=\sum\limits_{1\le i<j\le n} a_{ij}e_i\wedge e_j$

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $v=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_{1i}e_i$ and $w=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_{2i}e_i$ are $2$ vectors in $\mathbb R^n$, then one can write $v\wedge w$ as a linear combination of $\{e_i\wedge e_j:1\le i<j\le n\}$, what are then coefficients in that case, i.e. $v=\sum\limits_{1\le i<j\le n} a_{ij}e_i\wedge e_j$, how can I express $a_{ij}$ with $\lambda_{1i}$ and $\lambda_{2i}$ ?

Well there are $\binom{n}{2}$ possibilities for $e_i\wedge e_j$ so at least the combination of  $\lambda_{1i}$ and $\lambda_{2i}$ cannot be just the product

Comment: Use the skew-symmetry of the wedge product to reduce the number further.

Comment: @Paul but $i<j$ so it is already ordered

Comment: $\binom{n}{2}$ is for $i \leq j$, not $i<j$.

Comment: @Paul yes so $n^2-2n$ possibilites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't we try a little example and see if we can figure this out?

Suppose $v = a e_1 + b e_2$ and $w = c e_1 + d e_2$ (so either $n = 2$ or we decide all the other coefficients are zero). Then
\begin{align*}
v \wedge w
&= (a e_1 + b e_2) \wedge (c e_1 + d e_2)
\\
&= ac e_1 \wedge e_1
+ ad e_1 \wedge e_2
+ bc e_2 \wedge e_1
+ db e_2 \wedge e_2
\\
&= (ad - bc) e_1 \wedge e_2
\end{align*}
because $e_2 \wedge e_1 = - e_1 \wedge e_2$ (and $e_i \wedge e_i = 0$ for all $i$).

Can you now work out the general case? If not try another example with only three nonzero coefficients. It'll come.

Comment: Using this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/900866/337759 I get $a_{ij}=\lambda_{1i}\lambda_{2j}-\lambda_{1j}\lambda_{2i}$, I think its in accordance with your example, isn't it ?

Comment: It is, but you really should work through the calculations to get a feel for how they work. Once it clicks you'll know it forever.

Answer (score -1):

You're right that there are $\binom{n}{2}$ possibilities. However, remember that $e_k$ are all basis vectors (This is an assumption I'm making based on notation. If it were not for this, then I doubt there is a neat expression). Therefore, all of the $$a_{ij} = \lambda_{1i}\lambda_{2j}e_i \wedge e_j$$
Will be $0$ when $i \neq j$ since $e_i \wedge e_j = 0$

However, when $i = j$, then $e_i \wedge e_j = 1$

Therefore,

$$
a_{ij} = \lambda_{1i} \lambda_{2j} \ \ \ \text{when} \ \ \ i = j \\
a_{ij} = 0 \ \ \ \text{when} \ \ \ i \neq j
$$

However, since your index runs in a way that $i < j$, you can *never* have $i = j$. Therefore, the entire product collapses to $0$

Comment: but $i$ is never equal to $j$ in this representation as you can see in the middle line of the yellow box

Comment: @yasabur - I added a final note saying why this collapses. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: $e_i \wedge e_j = 0$ if $i = j$, but it is nonzero when $i \not= j$. The question is about the wedge product, which you don't seem to understand.